# correct use and best definition of “as in”

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I am translating an English text, which has the following sentence:

> The operative word is “protect”. **As in** protecting our religion.

First I would think that “as in” is a set phrase. But there is no definition that I was able to find after quite some searching.

So I would tend to think that then the meaning is literally “like in the phrase...”

Is that correct? Anybody can point me to a definition? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A word may be defined in more than one way or may have usage in more than one sense.

Explaining a word further with the phrase *as in* is to provide an example case where the meaning of the word is easily understood and thus acts to guide the reader.

In the instant case,

> … “protect”. As in protecting our religion. …

explains that the author used the word *protect* in the same sense as it is used in the phrase *protecting our religion*.

HTH.

See also:
[*as-in*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/as-in) (conjunctive) In the sense of
*Bow as in the weapon, not the front of a ship.*
along with
[*bow*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/bow)
on YourDictionary.com / [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_in)

Answer (score 13):

*As in* is what we call in English a **phrasal preposition**, which is simply when two or more words have been squeezed together to act as a preposition. The same concept applies to the phrases *out of*, *on top of*, *in front of*, *because of*, etc.

The phrasal preposition *as in* is commonly used to mean "which is..." or "which means..." and usually clarifies the meaning of a noun. Here are some examples to demonstrate this.

1. I like the bow (as in the weapon, not the front of the ship).
2. I like Jerry Lewis (as in our neighbor, not the comedian).

Sources

1. https://www.shmoop.com/grammar/prepositions/phrasal.html

Answer (score 4):

"As" is a conjunction and "in" is a preposition. "X as in Y" could be short for many different clauses as follows:

> as (X is meant) in Y
>
> as (they mean X) in Y
>
> as (X is used to mean X) in Y
>
> as (X could be synonymous with Y) in Y, etc.

The clauses in the parentheses could be understood contextually and there is no need to write them. "As in" doesn't necessarily mean "for example" or "like".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case it means "like in the phrase/example".

It is also used in some dictionary definitions. Here is means "has the meaning".

Eg.

> Clarify, verb
>
> 1. as in to filter
> 2. as in to explain

It is also used as a question in a discussion where one person is attempting to clarify the meaning of what the other person said. They do this by repeating back the meaning they think was intended. Here it means "do you mean?".

Eg.

> Person A: "The operative word is protect."
> Person B: "As in protect our religion?"

The question may also present multiple meanings as options.

Eg.

> Person A: "The operative word is protect."
> Person B: "As in protect our religion or protect our souls?"